# Looking for a chair that helps someone to hold a clarinet whilst playing

Tags: clarinet

I was wondering if anyone could please help me find out where I could purchase a chair to help my niece hold her clarinet whilst playing, as she is only young and a beginner and is slightly struggling with some of the harder notes, her tutor has asked her mum to get her a chair that has a sort of attachment on the front that will help her to hold up her clarinet whilst playing some of the harder notes. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I had not come across such things before but if you type Ergoclar into Google you will find, I think, precisely what you are looking for.   Looking at the first result returned [www.ergobrass.com](http://www.ergobrass.com) appear to have a dealer network where you can get a clarinet support that goes on a chair.

I expect there are plenty of others as well.

Hope that helps

Comment: As an occasional clarinet player, this is of great interest. So obvious an invention! +1

Comment: I did find those supports when I searched on Google but I've been told it's an actual chair with an attachment but thank you for your answer

Comment: I've seen (or at least seen videos) player using neck straps as well.  I'm not sure how they attach to the horn though.

Comment: @RachelDaly - it can't be a chair - there are different attachments which reach the floor as well as the shorter one which *rests* on a chair.

Comment: Ok thank you Tim, I'm just going by what the music instructor said as he said it was a chair. I'll have another look for the attachments only then. Thank you again